# Как из коллекции mongodb достать данные в виде?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
[
key : {
     value1 : '123',
     value2 : '123'
    }
]
```

вместо

```
[ 
   {
     value1 : '123',
     value2 : '123'
    } 
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас получается невалидный json:

```
[
key : {
     value1 : '123',
     value2 : '123'
    }
]
```

Предположу, что нужно получить все таки такой массив:

```
[
    {
        "key" : {
            "value1" : "123",
            "value2" : "123"
        }
    }
]
```

Тогда можно воспользоваться [map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/):

```
db.test.insert({value1: '123', value2: '123'})
db.test.find().map(function(e) {return {key: e};}
```

Comment: крутота, спасибо, получил что хотел